# Create new column with categorical values based on date dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I would like to create a new column which states whether the entry is a public holiday or not. It should look something like this:

```
             datetime                    holiday
0 2019-01-01 22:00:00                  public holiday
1 2019-01-01 23:00:00                  public holiday
2 2019-01-02 00:00:00                  non-holiday
3 2019-01-02 01:00:00                  non-holiday
4 2019-01-02 02:00:00                  non-holiday
```

I have made a dictionary containing all the holidays within my period which looks like this:

```
public_hol = {'xmas 18': '2018-12-25',
             'boxing day 18': '2018-12-25',
             'new years 19': '2019-01-01',
             'good friday 19': '2019-04-19',
             'easter monday 19': '2019-04-22',
             'may bank holiday': '2019-05-22',
             'may bank holiday2': '2019-05-27',
             'xmas 19': '2019-12-25',
             'boxing day 19': '2019-12-26',
             'new years 20': '2020-01-01'}
```

And this is my code:

```
df['holiday'] = df['datetime'].dt.date.map(public_hol).fillna('non-holiday')
```

This results in a new column which only contains NA's and hence only has 'non-holiday' for each entry. I think the issue is coming from the way I'm using the dictionary, or my code not recognising the date format... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use `map()`, you need to have your dictionary *keys* (rather than the *values*) match the data in your DataFrame or Series.

So:

1. You need to map *from* dates (`'2018-12-25'`) *to* their names (`'xmas 18'`).
2. You need to have those dates match the type of the dates in Pandas (`pd.Timestamp`), since that's what you're mapping.

You can adjust your current dictionary with the following command, which will invert the keys and values and convert the dates to a `pd.Timestamp` type:

```
public_hol = {
    pd.to_datetime(v): k
    for k, v in public_hol.items()
}
```

Or simply define the dictionary the right way from the start:

```
public_hol = {
    pd.to_datetime('2018-12-25'): 'xmas 18',
    pd.to_datetime('2018-12-26'): 'boxing day 18',
    ...
}
```

(Note that you seem to have some typos in your dictionary, you shouldn't have the same date twice, it can only map to a single holiday, currently you have 2018-12-25 for both "xmas" and "boxing day"...)